# Self hosted alternative to Picasa?

Tags: alternative, photo

Does anybody know a (free) alternative to Picasa, which I can host on my own server, or is there a way to host Picasa on my own server?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use WordPress with NextGEN gallery

http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/

It has a lot of add-on's and plenty of built in features.

Answer (score 1):

What features of Picasa do you need in special? Do you just want to store images on your Server or do you want to edit these too?

If you just need a storage system to share your pictures maybe something like ownCloud is a good alternative for you.

http://owncloud.org/

It's like dropbox or box.com - just hosted on your own server - you can store files, share them and so on ;) there are gallery-views too :)